# How can I rerender a template with an array after search?

Tags: symfony

I've made search functionality in symfony, which works.

```
public function forSaleAction(Request $request)
    {
        $data = array();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
            ->add('searchText')

            ->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);


        $ads = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('ParkResortBundle:Ad')
            ->findAll();

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            $SearchKeyword = $data['searchText'];
            $qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository('ParkResortBundle:Ad')->createQueryBuilder( 'p' );
            $qb->add( 'where',
                $qb->expr()->orX(
                    $qb->expr()->like( 'p.adTitle', "'%{$SearchKeyword}%'" ),
                    $qb->expr()->like( 'p.address', "'%{$SearchKeyword}%'" )

                )

            )
               ->addOrderBy('p.price', 'ASC');
            $ads = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();


        }

        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return $this->render('ParkResortBundle:Pages:_ad.html.twig',
                array('ads' => $ads));
        }

        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $paginated = $paginator->paginate(
            $ads, /* query NOT result */
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
            2/*limit per page*/
        );

        return $this->render('ParkResortBundle:Pages:forSale.html.twig',
            array('ads' => $paginated,
                  'form'=>$form->createView()));
    }
```

I want when the search area is empty(after user presses backspace or delete all) the list should appear all in for_sale twig template.

How can I do that?

Comment: you've missed calling `getEntityManager()` in `$ads = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('ParkResortBundle:Ad')
            ->findAll();`

Comment: @Noman you can call getRepository from Doctrine directly. It will get the EM by default `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry::getRepository()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use entity manager with `findAll()`

```
$ads = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
            ->getRepository('ParkResortBundle:Ad')
            ->findAll();
```

Comment: After I search for something and delete it  it won't display all the ads I have

Comment: you may need to dump what you getting in `$ads` before paginator.

Comment: yes it display me the good ads after the search.I want after empty the search field to load all the ads